# How to forward an email and change the subject using the Microsoft Graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

recently I ran into a problem where I was using python imap to automate outlook tasks, but microsft changed basic auth to Oauth now, and I have not being able to authenticate ever since, I get an error

```
imaplib.error: AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

So I started working with the Microsoft graph API, in which I can get the information that I need but once I need to forward an email I can't setup a custom subject, I can just add a comment and toRecepient custom arguments.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-forward?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
any advice here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Create-Forward endpoint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-createforward that will create a draft message of the forward which you can then patch any message property you want to update and then send.

The one thing they don't mention in the documentation is you should set the Prefer: outlook.timezone header to make sure the dates in you response are set the local time of the responder.